# ERROR 2997: Unable to recreate exception from backed error: while using CSVExcelStorage

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

ERROR 2997: Unable to recreate exception from backed error.
Here i have parsed apache log file but when i am trying to export it into csv format this error occurs. Code and error :

```
grunt> STORE logs  INTO '/home/cloudera/workspace/Test_log.csv' USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVExcelStorage(',', 'NO_MULTILINE','NOCHANGE');
```

> 2015-12-24 10:50:44,821 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.ScriptState - Pig features used in the
>   script: UNKNOWN
>
> 2015-12-24 10:50:44,830 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MRCompiler
>   - File concatenation threshold: 100 optimistic? false
>
> 2015-12-24 10:50:44,937 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler
>   - mapred.job.reduce.markreset.buffer.percent is not set, set to default 0.3
>
> 2015-12-24 10:50:49,055 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler
>   - Setting up single store job
>
> 2015-12-24 10:50:49,056 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.data.SchemaTupleFrontend - Key [pig.schematuple] is
>   false, will not generate code.
>
> 2015-12-24 10:50:49,056 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.data.SchemaTupleFrontend - Starting process to move
>   generated code to distributed cache
>
> 2015-12-24 10:50:49,056 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.data.SchemaTupleFrontend - Setting key
>   [pig.schematuple.classes] with classes to deserialize []
>
> 2015-12-24 10:50:49,158 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher
>   - 1 map-reduce job(s) waiting for submission.
>
> 2015-12-24 10:50:49,158 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.job.tracker
>   is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.jobtracker.address
>
> 2015-12-24 10:50:49,159 [JobControl] INFO 
>   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy - Connecting to ResourceManager
>   at /0.0.0.0:8032
>
> 2015-12-24 10:50:49,177 [JobControl] INFO 
>   org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - fs.default.name is
>   deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS
>
> 2015-12-24 10:50:49,428 [JobControl] INFO 
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat - Total input
>   paths to process : 1
>
> 2015-12-24 10:50:49,431 [JobControl] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.util.MapRedUtil - Total
>   input paths (combined) to process : 2
>
> 2015-12-24 10:50:49,467 [JobControl] INFO 
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter - number of splits:2
>
> 2015-12-24 10:50:49,518 [JobControl] INFO 
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter - Submitting tokens for job:
>   job_1450979216927_0004
>
> 2015-12-24 10:50:49,578 [JobControl] INFO 
>   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.YarnClientImpl - Submitted
>   application application_1450979216927_0004
>
> 2015-12-24 10:50:49,581 [JobControl] INFO 
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job - The url to track the job:
>   http://quickstart.cloudera:8088/proxy/application_1450979216927_0004/
>
> 2015-12-24 10:50:49,659 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher
>   - HadoopJobId: job_1450979216927_0004
>
> 2015-12-24 10:50:49,659 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher
>   - Processing aliases logs
>
> 2015-12-24 10:50:49,659 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher
>   - detailed locations: M: logs[7,7],null[-1,-1] C:  R:
>
> 2015-12-24 10:50:49,659 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher
>   - More information at: http://localhost:50030/jobdetails.jsp?jobid=job_1450979216927_0004
>
> 2015-12-24 10:50:49,702 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher
>   - 0% complete
>
> 2015-12-24 10:51:17,030 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher
>   - 50% complete
>
> 2015-12-24 10:52:04,848 [main] WARN 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher
>   - Ooops! Some job has failed! Specify -stop_on_failure if you want Pig to stop immediately on failure.
>
> 2015-12-24 10:52:04,848 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher
>   - job job_1450979216927_0004 has failed! Stop running all dependent jobs
>
> 2015-12-24 10:52:04,848 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher
>   - 100% complete
>
> 2015-12-24 10:52:05,039 [main] ERROR
>   org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.SimplePigStats - ERROR 2997: Unable to
>   recreate exception from backed error:
>   AttemptID:attempt_1450979216927_0004_m_000001_3 Info:Error:
>   org.apache.pig.data.Tuple.isNull()Z
>
> 2015-12-24 10:52:05,040 [main] ERROR
>   org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.PigStatsUtil - 1 map reduce job(s)
>   failed! 2015-12-24
>   10:52:05,040[main]INFOorg.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.SimplePigStats -
>   Script Statistics:
>
> HadoopVersion PigVersion  UserId  StartedAt   FinishedAt  Features
>   2.6.0-cdh5.4.0    0.12.0-cdh5.4.0 cloudera    2015-12-24 10:50:44 2015-12-24 10:52:05 UNKNOWN
>
> Failed!
>
> Failed Jobs: JobId    Alias   Feature Message Outputs
>   job_1450979216927_0004    logs    MAP_ONLY    Message: Job
>   failed!   /home/cloudera/workspace/Test_log.csv,
>
> Input(s): Failed to read data from "/myhdfs/project/TestLog.txt"
>
> Output(s): Failed to produce result in
>   "/home/cloudera/workspace/Test_log.csv"
>
> Counters: Total records written : 0 Total bytes written : 0 Spillable
>   Memory Manager spill count : 0 Total bags proactively spilled: 0 Total
>   records proactively spilled: 0
>
> Job DAG: job_1450979216927_0004
>
> 2015-12-24 10:52:05,040 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher
>   - Failed!

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be an error in your dataprocessing chain. This log entry points out that a tuple is null. Just an idea: This can happen, eg when you use customized UDFs, which return Null in some cases.

```
2015-12-24 10:52:05,039 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.SimplePigStats - ERROR 2997: Unable to recreate exception from backed error: AttemptID:attempt_1450979216927_0004_m_000001_3 Info:Error: org.apache.pig.data.Tuple.isNull()Z
```

Comment: I removed the stuff that is not really an answer from your answer. To request clarification from OP, please use a comment (requires 50 rep).

Comment: Sure, makes sense thanks. But i would have added it as a comment, when i'd have enough rep. I have < 50 rep :-)

Comment: Yes, I saw that. We needed this restriction due to too many problematic comments by new users, see [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214173/311792) Tl;dr: The best solution from your point of view is "Get some rep". =D